# Ext.Net :Special Turkish characters displays wrong

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

I am using Ext.Net community version 2.0.0

special Turkish characters**  displays wrong.

special Turkish characters displays wrong.(for all browser,displayed wrong format )
dateField control(calender) and some notification tool tip shows wrong format as well.

for example : it has to be shown like this "Mayıs "and "Ağustos", however ,It appears something like this "MayÃ½s" "AÃ°ustos"

*I add a image that show the error.On the image ,it has to be written "Şubat 2014" But it seems strange

*I am using UTF-8 encoding as well.

**special turkish characters= ş,ğ,ı,ü,ö,ç,Ş,Ğ,Ü,Ö

what can I do to fix that problem.

thank you

[image]

Comment: I have already used UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a related [thread](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?23017) on the Ext.NET forums.